# Merge and mix all values from columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I need to generate all possible mixed values from columns in Google Sheets

### Input data:

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

### Should create values like

A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way (i think)
Assuming that your values in columns B and C

First go and assign content od 2nd column to each element of 1st column:

```
=join(", ",ArrayFormula(B3&$C$3:$C$5))
```

Then
Combine newly made values into one cell

```
=textjoin(", ",1,D3:D)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any option that it'd automatycally adjust for rows that are empty?

Comment: Sure. Wrap first formula with =iferror(join(", ",ArrayFormula(B3&$C$3:$C$5))) so you will have blank rows. Textjoin formula should be o.k. with this as it's set to ignore empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try, for an output

- in a single column

  =flatten(ArrayFormula(A1:A3&transpose(B1:B3)))
- in a single row

  =transpose(flatten(ArrayFormula(A1:A3&transpose(B1:B3))))
- in a single cell

  =join(", ", flatten(ArrayFormula(A1:A3&transpose(B1:B3))))

Change range to suit and see if any of these formulas helps?

If you want to filter out the rows with a single character, you can try

```
=query(flatten(ArrayFormula(A1:A4&transpose(B1:B4))), "where Col1 matches '^.{2,}'")
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! Is there a way to filter out single elements, like "A" and "1", so there will be only combined elements "XN"?